# How to run the packaged application from django's polls tutorial?

Tags: django

```
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/reusable-apps/
```

After it's packaged, the documentation says that 'With luck, your Django project should now work correctly again. Run the server again to confirm this.'. In this tutorial, to start the server, do this:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

But after this is packaged and installed to the user directory, it has been moved out of the project, and 'manage.py' isn't available. How to run the server and test the newly installed package?

This may be a silly question, but the doc does lack a key sentence to tell how to start the server to run the installed package.

Comment: Did you install it with `pip` as stated in the tutorial? You are moving your reusable app out of your project, because then you got to install it via pip (like other third party applications). Those apps don't have a `manage.py` like a "normal" django project because they are "just apps". app != project

Comment: Yes. I did. The question, how to 'Run the server again to confirm this' according to doc?

Comment: I think what is meant is that the new package should be installed in the Mysite directory / environment (where it came from). The manage.py of the project Mysite is still there, so it is possible to run python manage.py runserver from there.

Comment: pip install --user... If you go back to there to run the command, then it would still run the unpackaged project, not the installed one.

Comment: Why does the packaging not include the 'manage.py' and the 'mysite' directory? Which is an integral part of the app. Right?

Comment: For a reusable app the manage.py is not needed, no. It is needed for the project itself, but you are making a reusable `app`, not a reusable `project`. Thats why only the app-directory is included.

Comment: @wfehr then how and where to start the server after it's packaged and installed per the documentation?

Comment: You still have your project folder with the manage.py, and this is used to start the server. The only difference now is that you dont have your app directly inside your project as a folder, but you have installed it as a package via pip now.

Comment: @wfehr OK, i see. It's going to be a new 'manage.py' in my new project, not the one in the original project used in the polls demo. Because of that, I need to change the setting in the new manage.py, 'os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')', where 'mysite.settings' is for the polls demo only. Right?